# Query geodatabase with PostgreSQL to show - schema, table, column, domain name

Tags: postgresql, arcgis-10.1, sql, esri-geodatabase, query

How to query geodatabase system tables using PostgreSQL to result this:

schema, table, column, domain name

I found this, but nothing for PostgreSQL
https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/query-system-tables-with-sql.htm

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: As this is more a database question than a GIS question (even if this is a spatial database) you may get more answer on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: A somewhat related oracle post here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/215618/list-of-all-fields-and-their-domains-for-each-table-using-sql-table-name-field

Comment: How far can you get by poking around the GDB tables in your SQL client? https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/overview-geodatabase-system-tables.htm, https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/gdbs-in-postgresql/system-tables-postgresql.htm

Comment: @J.R The fourth element in the list, domain name, is only available in XML metadata within the Enterprise geodatabase tables, so this is an Esri-specific question.